# Merge two QMenuBar

Tags: qt

I have to Qt project, and one of them (B) is based on the first one (A). How can I complete the QMenuBar of B with the elements of the QMenuBar of A ?
For a better comprehension :

This is A QMenuBar :

```
 MenuA1   MenuA2
   -op1     -op1
   -op2     -op2
```

This is B QMenuBar :

```
 MenuB1   MenuA1    MenuA2
   -op1     -op1      -op1
   -op2     -op2      -op2
```

Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

It seems the is no nice way to retrieve the Menus of a QMenuBar once it has been constructed.

I'd store the pointers of the `QMenus` added to `QMenuBar A` to add them if needed to the `QMenuBar B` using `addMenu(...)`.

Comment: It was my first idea too. But I'm looking for a better solution... Is it possible to herit B from A ?

Comment: No, that can not work. You may inherit from QMenuBar and provide `addMenu()` methods which store the added `QMenus` pointers in an accessible list before delivered to the `addMenu()` method of QMenuBar.